# Requested entity was not found FCM iOS React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios

I can’t get push notifications to work on iOS. On android, everything is OK which confirms that the problem comes from my configuration.
I am able to retrieve a FCM token with iOS (which is 163 characters long) by using the `firebase.messaging().getToken()` function.
However, when I use this token to send a push notification, nothing happens (in the Firebase console). And when my partner (back-end) sends a push notification from our server, he receives a `Requested entity was not found.`

I added the Push notification capability to my project. I created an “APN” key from my Apple Developer account that I added correctly in the Firebase console. I also added a development and production certificate for the push notifications (to make sure the problem couldn’t come from the fact that he couldn’t send the pushes with the APN key).

What I don't understand is that I'm able to retrieve the FCM token but it seems that it is invalid at the time of generation. At the time, when I was using FCM 6, I had to make some updates in my AppDelegate.m but now, since I'm using FCM 7, I followed installation process again, and so I deleted all the changes I had made in the AppDelegate.m.

Are there any changes to be made to AppDelegate.m or the project that are not mentioned in the FCM installation process? How do I know if the error is due to FCM or perhaps due to APNS?

I'm running out of ideas in terms of solutions or questions to ask myself to try and solve the problem.

Comment: add a token refresh method using useEffect, use firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(token => {})

Comment: which version you rn firebase you are using

Comment: I'm already using `onTokenRefresh` and I declare the listener, either in my `componentDidMount` of my `App` component if my user is already logged, either when my user just logged. I'm using FCM 7.8.6.